# How to make a desktop shortcut to Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, scheduled-tasks

I have many tasks that I am tinkering with in Windows Task Scheduler. I would like to add a desktop shortcut that I can click to open the Scheduler. theSoftwareJedi's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396099/how-to-launch-windows-scheduler-by-command-line) shows the following command does what I want from the command line. How do I embed it into a desktop shortcut? I am using Windows 7.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\taskschd.msc /s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the desktop, make a rightclick, select `New`->`Shortcut`, insert the command `%windir%\system32\taskschd.msc /s` give it a name and select the icon from the Windows file `%windir%\system32\miguiresource.dll`.

Comment: I am going to be using this solution every day so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Press your Start button → search for Task Scheduler → Right Click → Send to → Desktop

Comment: In Windows 7, I don't seem to have the option to search from the Start button. Instead it seems like I have to go to Help and search for Schedule there, get a help page which includes a link to Schedule a Task, and click on that link to open Scheduler. Let me know if I am missing something though.